# How to create bootstrap page header navbar with static subitems?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create page header menu by bootstrap like image below (I am wondering how to create "+" link below the Contact menu ). Can anybody help?

```
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Index", "Contacts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Index", "Settings")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that either by adding a span in the `li`, or by targeting the first list element and using the pseudo-element `::after`
Here is an example using `::after`:
http://jsfiddle.net/8gj1wsca/

Comment: No I can't. It seems terrible then. Let's try (with bootstrap template).

Comment: I gave you a working fiddle based on your request, if you need anything else, post a fiddle of your current code.

Comment: My ask is not about functionality but just about layout. In your fiddle you have vertical layout, it's unusable for me. I need the layout just like in my image example - it's bootstrap default styling.

Comment: You asked how to add the "+" to the layout you want to create. And just posted the HTML. I sent you a fiddle with what you need to add that + in your list. Proceed to style your header, or post a fiddle, I don't know how many times I must ask.